# how do foreign key works in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So i have read [here](http://linuxers.org/howto/myisam-or-innodb-mysql-engine) that MyISAM is the default engine for MYSQL and it does not support foreign keys, But i have created a table just now and forgot to put `ENGINE=INNODB`, it still have my defined foreign key. My MySQL version is 14.14 by the way. And i used this code to make my foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  my_foreign_key_fk INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (my_foreign_key_fk) REFERENCES sometable(primary_key_pk)
);
```

and here's how i checked and assumed that my foreign key were implemented:

```
DESC my_table
```

which displayed like this on the **key column**:

```
Field             |Key
------------------|----
my_foreign_key_fk |MUL
```

So can someone enlighten me on this one?

Comment: There is no version `14.14` of MySQL.

Comment: it says here, when i do mysql --version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MyISAM you can *create* the FK, it just doesn't *do* anything, such as support [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

Comment: can you provide me an example sir why i would want a referential integrity?

Comment: You have a customer. The customer has invoices. You delete the customer. You now have invoices that belong to no customer. **OOPS.**

Comment: So it's like cascading deletion? when i implement a foreign key, it automatically deletes all that is related to it?

Comment: It's like not screwing up your data because someone slipped.

Comment: Hey, how come all my tables now are in INNODB engine? i thought MyISAM is the default, i didnt manually set the tables.

Comment: Dunno. Maybe someone changed the config.

Comment: can you vote up my post and link this to your friends so they can vote this up too? thanks

Comment: @user2484763: why should anyone upvote your question? It is something that is being asked about once a week and apparently you did not do any research (neither by reading the manual - where this is documente nor by searching the web) You didn't even get the MySQL version right. So: why should anyone upvote such a question?